Prove that $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & x \le 1 \\ 2x & x \gt 1 \end{cases}$ is not differentiable at $x = 1$
I'm going through Etgen's One and several variables (a book on calculus), and I came across  the following question: Prove that the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 & x \le 1 \\
2x & x \gt 1
\end{cases}$$
is not differentiable at $x = 1$. Using the definition of the derivative (the limit as $h \to 0$ of the difference quotient; i.e., $\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{f (c + h) - f(c)}{h} \right)$), I found that the value of that limit of both the LHS and RHS is equal to $2$, so I assumed the limit must exist. But I also found that this function is not continuous at $x = 1$, so it should not be differentiable at that point.
In the same book, we had to prove that if the limit of the difference quotient exists at a real number $c$, then $f (x)$ is continuous at that point. I feel like I must be making a mistake somewhere, or misunderstanding what the definition of the limit is, so any help is appreciated.

It's not enough to check that the left limit and right limit of the difference quotient both exist and are equal.  You have to show that the (two-sided) limit exists.  Since the function is discontinuous, the two-sided limit doesn't exist.

Ah I see. I assumed that if the function was discontinuous, calculating the limit of the difference quotient would reflect that.

It does.  That limit here goes to $\infty$ when you pick a secant that spans the discontinuity.

differentiable implies continues which is not the case here.

The RHL is not equal to $2$!  $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac {f(1+h) -f(1)}h = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac {2(1+h) - 1^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac {1+2h}h=2+\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac 1h=\infty$.

Note that if $c=1\le 1$ then $f(c) = c^2$ but as $c + h > 1$ then $f(c+h) = 2(c+h)$.  So $f(c+h) - f(c) = 2(c+h) - c^2$ and we don't get a nice limit at all.  $2(c+h)-c^2= (2c-c^2) + 2h$ and $\frac {f(c+h)-f(c)}h = \frac {(2c-c^2) +2h}h= \frac {2c-c^2}h + 2$ and the $h$ doesn't cancel out nicely at all.

Thanks to these comments and the answer, I can see the error I made (I commented on the accepted answer). To confirm, if the first case was strictly for $x \lt 1$, would $f(x)$ be differentiable at 1?

Oh... d'oh!  Of course not.  If $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=c$ then $f(c+h) -f(c)$ is greater than some constant so so limit is infinite.

If not continuous at $x=c$ then there exists a $\delta$ so that for any $h$ there is an $x_0$ so that even though $|x_0 - c|<h$ that $|f(x_0) -f(c)| > \delta$.  So $|\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h) - f(h)}h| >\lim_{h\to 0}|\frac {\delta}h| = \infty$.  Can't be differential at a discontinuity as the difference between $f(c)$ and $f(close\ to\ c)$ is a measurable real actual gap.  The entire premise of a derivative is the assumption $f(close\ to\ c)$ is close to $f(c)$. And that assumes a continuity. and wo it derivatives are meaningless.

Your difference quotient limits are not correct. For your function, $f (1) = (1)^2 = 1$. Let's consider the difference quotients from the left and right.
From the left:
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f (1) - f (1 - h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{1 - (1 - h)^2}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{2 h - h^2}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} (2 - h) = 2$$
which is what you got.
But from the right:
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f (1 + h) - f (1)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{2 (1 + h) - 1}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \left( 2 + \frac{1}{h} \right) = \infty$$
It is a helpful and easy exercise to prove that in general, if the derivative of $f (x)$ exists at a point $x = x_0$, then the function must be continuous at $x_0$. In your case, since $f (x)$ is not continuous at $x = 1$, then the derivative of $f (x)$ must not exist there.

But from the right, $f(1) = 2(1) = 2$? Why is it equal to 1?

From the definition of your function, $f (1) = 1$.

Ooooooh! $f(x)$ is $x^2$ at $x = 1$!!! I forgot the upper inequality was less than or equal to!!! I knew I was making an error. Thank you

Yes, that is correct. Glad to help!

So, just to confirm, if the upper inequality was strict i.e $f(x) = x^2, x \lt 1$, would that function be differentiable at $x = 1$?

Well, then the function wouldn't even be defined at $x = 1$, so it's unclear what is meant by differentiable at the point.
